# Upload file and thumbnail with Lifecycle Callbacks Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, file-upload

First of all, sorry for my bad english, I´m working on it...

I read the cookbook "How to handle File Uploads" for `Symfony2`.I've implemented the entity and at this point it works correctly.

In this case, I have to upload a lot of photos with their respective thumbnails keeping the path of both in the database. My first choice was create two entities Image and Thumbnail with OnetoOne relation, but the son entity can´t catch the file received from the form of parent entity.

My second choice was make it all in one entity, with two attributes `($path and $thumbpath)` and call two upload methods with the same file, and in the `uploadthumb()` method make the resize. But it throws this error: `" The file "image.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error. "`

I had a look to liipimagineBundle and some others, but only create the thumbnails in the fly and don´t stores this like an entity, only in the cache.

Can someone give me an idea of how to make it in the most eficient way?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was not answered, I wanted to show another bundle that greatly helps with uploads in Symfony2 - [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).  I used it to upload images and create a thumbnail in one entity with two fields - one for the full filename, and one for the thumbnail name, plus this works with multiple front ends so you can customize the look for the user easily.

In the OneupUploaderBundle EventListener, I added another function that resized the file already uploaded and then saved it in the same location with thumb added to the filename.  It is a clean approach and works smoothly.

Comment: Can you give us more details? Thanks!